# Problem with React Router - page renders before effect sets state with api call response

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-router, react-context

I am having a strange problem with my React application.
It is a mock vinyl shop and now I am working on the "previous orders" functionality. I am sending a GET request with my token to my back end  within a useEffect block and setting the state of orders. The token itself I am getting via a context wrapper.
Then my component is supposed to render the results.
The code is below:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContextProvider';

import { fetchAllOrders } from '../api/api';
import OrderDetails from './OrderDetails';


export const Orders = () => {
    const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
    const token = authCtx.loggedInUserData.auth_token
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getAllOrders() {
            console.log("effect ran", token)
            const response = await fetchAllOrders(token);
            console.log(response)

            setOrders(response);
            // setOrders(response.data);       // when using axios
        }

        getAllOrders();
    }, [token]);

    console.log(orders)
    return (
        <main>
            {orders.length > 0 && { token } && <div>
                {orders.map(order =>
                    <OrderDetails key={order.id} order={order} />
                )}
            </div>
            }
        </main>
    )

}
```

The puzzling bit is that the component works as expected and renders the data when I access it from within the application itself. The api call accesses the correct endpoint, auth middleware is passed successfully, the response is in the correct format and eventually it displays on my FE.

[image: successful api call and rendering results]

However once I refresh the tab or type directly in the address bar `http://localhost:3001/orders` I get 401 error.

[image: 401 error - page rendering before response is received]

As you can see it looks like in the second instance the effect runs before the token is obtained and sent to the api, hence the 401 response. Why would this be happening?
Also after the error is thrown I seem to get the expected response but obviously the app has crashed by then. Once I add proper error handling this would probably no longer be an issue?
I simply don't understand why would the app behave differently in those 2 scenarios.
By the way the whole [app could be found here](https://github.com/karalkal/vinyl-shop--express-BE) as there might be other moving parts affecting this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no condition on the fetching of data, it's made regardless of `token` value. You may wish to modify the effect to only make the fetch request when there's a defined token value.

Additionally, when rendering the results, `{ token }` is an object and so it will ***always*** be truthy, use *just* `token` instead to help conditionally the results when (a) there are results to render and (b) a truthy token used to fetch them.

If `orders` is an array, then it should ***always*** be an array type. This is to maintain a state invariant that is easy to reason about.

Example:

```
export const Orders = () => {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  const token = authCtx.loggedInUserData.auth_token;

  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]); // <-- array invariant

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getAllOrders() {
      const response = await fetchAllOrders(token);
      setOrders(response);
    }

    if (token) {
      getAllOrders(); // <-- only fetch orders if truthy token
    }
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <main>
      {!!orders.length && token && (
        <div>
          {orders.map(order =>
            <OrderDetails key={order.id} order={order} />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  );
};
```

Comment: After some testing I came to the conclusion that useContext perhaps runs  asynchronously. Is this so? 
In the original code the effect will run before the token variable gets its value from the context, hence the 401 error. When I provide the token value directly (let token=[whatever]) this is not happening.

Comment: @karalkal No, all React hooks are synchronous functions. The `useContext` hook simply returns the current context value when it is called. *However*, some value the context is providing may be updated asynchronously. I hope this makes sense.